# Sagepay iframe Integration Issues Using IE 10 Windows 8 Metro

Tags: iframe, microsoft-metro, opayo

I am experiencing problems with sage pay iframe integration but only when using IE 10 running in Metro mode under Windows 8.

Running the same web site using IE 10 Windows 8 desktop mode runs fine.

The error that I am seeing is:

> Error from Sage Pay: 5004 : The Transaction state is invalid.

As a precautionary measure I turned  off "Enable Protected Mode" in IE but this did not stop the error occurring.

Comment: At what point does the error occur?

Comment: After card has been authorised IE 10 in metro mode displays this message:

"To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend the information you've previously submitted. If you were making a purchase, you should click Cancel to avoid a duplicate transaction. Otherwise, click retry to display the webpage again."

I believe it is clicking on "retry" which causes the 5004 error but having trouble finding out what causes the above message to be displayed just in IE 10 metro mode.

Comment: I reported this bug to sagepay support a while ago - I never heard back - the problem is that when you click retry it submits the original request for the form - which has already been processed and so the error is caused. I suggest that you report the issue to sagepay technical support too - the will ask for screen shots, and if possible a fiddler trace.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Carl.

I am contact with sage and it is good to know that someone has experienced the same issue. 

I have spent too much time trying to find a java script bug in our own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this issue.

It was caused by custom mark-up that is applied via the MySage control panel.